# Can I fly from Belgium to Germany with Belgian Residence Card Type E for identification?

Tags: schengen, belgium, eu-citizens, spanish-citizens

My Spanish ID has expired and I am unable to go to Spain until September. In addition, my Spanish passport is at the Chinese Consulate in Brussels in order to get a visitor visa for travel at the end of this month.

And tomorrow, I will take a flight to Hamburg (Germany) from Brussels and the only proof of identification I have at the moment is my Belgian residence card, type E.

The airline is Brussels Airlines. Can I fly to Germany with my Belgian ID?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:customs-and-immigration] for an internal Schengen (end EU internal) flight? And why [tag:spanish-language]?

Comment: I see you haven't visited since May 5th.  If you come back to the site, please post an answer describing your experience.

Answer (score 1):

> [Travel documents for EU nationals](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm)
>
> If you are an EU national , you do not need to show your national ID card or passport when you are travelling from one border-free Schengen EU country to another.
>
> Even if you don't need a passport for border checks within the Schengen area , it is still always highly recommended to take a passport or ID card with you, so you can prove your identity if needed (if stopped by police, boarding a plane, etc.). Schengen EU countries have the possibility of adopting national rules obliging you to hold or carry papers and documents when you are present on their territory.

Comment: Airlines can and often do have stricter rules about identification.

Comment: @phoog you're absolutely right, of course. Hopefully, OP will return and share his experience.

Answer (score 1):

At the Brussels airport, you will never need to show your ID when traveling to Germany. You just swipe your boarding pass (print it ahead of time) and go through the automated gate. They will not check at the gate either.

Same goes for Hamburg. I have personally flown the route you are describing without ID, with two caveats:

1. If you check luggage they may ask to see your ID.
2. As the above answer states, technically you need valid ID in Schengen because you can be stopped at any time. That has nothing to do with the aviation industry.